# PDO queries working on localhost but not on webserver -- how to debug the issue?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some pages that make PDO queries using prepare() and execute() (binding some parameters) and they work fine on localhost, but are failing online with messages like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 INSERT command denied to user ...
```

How do I debug this? I have no idea what is wrong, as it works on my development server (localhost), and I am new to PDO and don't know what to do.

I should also note that at least some of the PDO queries are working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear, the user you are using on your webserver does not have permission to insert a record. You need to set the correct permissions using the mysql command line or something like phpMyAdmin if you have it installed on the web-server.

Comment: The user has all privileges. Also, in phpMyAdmin I can insert rows.

Comment: @Nate Using the exact same user? If so, are the database and the php script on the same server?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you have limited permission on that mysql server, try run the query in phpMyAdmin and see if you get the same error.

Comment: i got the same problem except pdo says nothing and phpMyAmin works just fine!